# php glob raises value to 1 if no file was found

Tags: php, glob

I have a problem with the PHP function glob().

```
$array=glob("*.html");
```

sizeof($array) contains 1 if no html file was found. print_r also does not return any value.
If one html file was found, sizeof($array) also returns 1 and print_r contains one filename.

Why does glob raise the value from 0 to 1 if nothing is inside the array?
So, it is not possible to check, if no file was found by glob.

Does anyone know a workaround?

Comment: Please do a `var_dump($array);`, and show us what _exactly_ that results in.

Comment: PHP 5.3.3 has a bug in glob(), with PHP 7.2 it works fine.

Comment: _“`sizeof($array)` contains 1 if no html file was found”_ - because you don’t have an actual array in that case, you are using `sizeof` on a boolean `false`. (Get into the habit of using `var_dump` for debug outputs instead of `print_r`, getting the _type_ shown as well is helpful in cases like this.) So just use `is_array` or do a strict comparison `!== false` for a “workaround” …

Comment: sizeof: 1 - count: 1
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "1.png"
}



sizeof: 1 - count: 1
bool(false)

Comment: (Not sure about the PHP version you mentioned though, anything below 5.4.45 actually appears to return an empty array - https://3v4l.org/j5CEd)

Comment: yes, thx for idea. in PHP 7.2 the glob() return always 0 if no file was found